# Faulting module name: sqlite3odbc.dll

Tags: dll, sql-server-2012

My SQL server 2012 keeps crashing with MSSQLSERVER service terminated unexpectedly. If i look in even viewer the only thing I see is an error.

> Faulting application name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2011.110.6020.0,
>   time stamp: 0x5626ed31
>
> Faulting module name: sqlite3odbc.dll, version: 0.9993.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x5693826f

I am using the datasource connection to read a spiceworks database into SQL so that i can run queries against it. I have no idea what is causing this as it worked for about 2 weeks and now i get this error and SQL restart randomly every few hours.

I have un-installed and re-installed. I have replacd the DLL. I have recreated datasource connection. Would a restart fix this issue (have not tried this as downtime is a major issue for this SQL box)?

Any assistance or guidance would be appreciated.